# Coding no latency buttons

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, microcontroller

I am making shifter, so when i put it in first gear it must click a button and stand on it for a while. That's how it looks ingame: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NDuPH02xWp8

```py
import time
import board
import digitalio
import usb_hid
from adafruit_hid.keycode import Keycode
from adafruit_hid.keyboard import Keyboard
from adafruit_hid.keyboard_layout_us import KeyboardLayoutUS
from adafruit_hid.consumer_control import ConsumerControl
from adafruit_hid.consumer_control_code import ConsumerControlCode

keyboard = Keyboard(usb_hid.devices)

# Define the buttons
btn1 = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.GP0)
btn2 = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.GP1)
btn3 = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.GP2)
btn4 = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.GP3)
btn5 = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.GP4)
btn6 = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.GP5)
btn7 = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.GP6)
btn8 = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.GP7)
btn9 = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.GP8)

# Set the buttons as inputs
btn1.direction = digitalio.Direction.INPUT
btn2.direction = digitalio.Direction.INPUT
btn3.direction = digitalio.Direction.INPUT
btn4.direction = digitalio.Direction.INPUT
btn5.direction = digitalio.Direction.INPUT
btn6.direction = digitalio.Direction.INPUT
btn7.direction = digitalio.Direction.INPUT
btn8.direction = digitalio.Direction.INPUT
btn9.direction = digitalio.Direction.INPUT

while True:
    if btn1.value:
        keyboard.send(30)
    if btn2.value:
        keyboard.send(31)
```

This is a circuitpython code and the problem is it does not hold the button.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong method, as the [documentation](https://docs.circuitpython.org/projects/hid/en/latest/api.html) says:

> `send(*keycodes: int) → None`
> Press the given keycodes and then **release** all pressed keys.

(Emphasis by me.)

If you want more control, use these methods:

> `press(*keycodes: int) → None`
> Send a report indicating that the given keys have been pressed.

and

> `release(*keycodes: int) → None`
> Send a USB HID report indicating that the given keys have been released.